# How to return a childobject from json with lodash?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

Suppose I have the following json file and I would like to return the 'existing.primaryBundle.products' array preferrably with lodash:

```
{
  "existing": {
    "hasPlatinum": false,
    "primaryBundle": {
      "id": "2008",
      "name": "TV - Entertainment, Sport",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Entertainment",
          "id": "100",
          "price": 2600,
          "gifted": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Sport",
          "id": "107",
          "price": 2500,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [
            {
              "name": "Movies",
              "id": "105",
              "price": 2000,
              "gifted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "extrasBundle": {
      "id": "131",
      "name": "Optional Extras - MUTV (Sports), LFCTV (Sports), Chelsea TV (Sports)",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "MUTV (Sports)",
          "id": "665",
          "price": 0,
          "gifted": false
        },
        {
          "name": "LFCTV (Sports)",
          "id": "666",
          "price": 0,
          "gifted": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Chelsea TV (Sports)",
          "id": "667",
          "price": 0,
          "gifted": false
        }
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

I have tried lodash and use this statement:

list2 = _.pick(existing,'primaryBundle.products')

But this returns an error and not the wanted result. How can I select this products array?

Comment: Assuming you've parsed the JSON *string* to get an object `obj`, you can just say `list2 = obj.existing.primaryBundle.products`. No need for Lodash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `_.get(nameOfObject, 'existing.primaryBundle.products')` of course you would need to name your object like I've done below with `sampleObject`;

check out the lodash [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) too

```
const sampleObject = {
  "existing": {
    "hasPlatinum": false,
    "primaryBundle": {
      "id": "2008",
      "name": "TV - Entertainment, Sport",
      "products": [{
        "name": "Entertainment",
        "id": "100",
        "price": 2600,
        "gifted": false
      }, {
        "name": "Sport",
        "id": "107",
        "price": 2500,
        "gifted": false,
        "swappableProducts": [{
          "name": "Movies",
          "id": "105",
          "price": 2000,
          "gifted": false
        }]
      }]
    },
    "extrasBundle": {
      "id": "131",
      "name": "Optional Extras - MUTV (Sports), LFCTV (Sports), Chelsea TV (Sports)",
      "products": [{
        "name": "MUTV (Sports)",
        "id": "665",
        "price": 0,
        "gifted": false
      }, {
        "name": "LFCTV (Sports)",
        "id": "666",
        "price": 0,
        "gifted": false
      }, {
        "name": "Chelsea TV (Sports)",
        "id": "667",
        "price": 0,
        "gifted": false
      }]
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.get(sampleObject, 'existing.primaryBundle.products'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why it returns an error is because `existing` is not a global scoped object, you have to assign object to some variable like `const obj = {...}` and then pass the parameter to `_pick` method as `obj.existing`, yet I don't see a reason to use lodash in here, you can just reference the path to that object directly.